# Click button twice to confirm action

Tags: c#, wpf, confirmation

So I want to find a way to make the user confirm their actions by clicking a button twice using **single clicks.** 
On the first time it would display the warning via a hidden label and start a timer which would count for a few seconds. Then if the user clicks the button again (before the timeout) it executes the code. 
If left the label would hide and the user would have to click 2 times again to run the code. 
Would the best approach involve an if argument and global variable. As I was thinking something like this 
(I know it's not in c# but it's a good visual representation of what I'm talking about):

```
Var buttonclick = 0
if buttonclick = 0
{Show warning label
Start timer 
Set Var buttonclick = 1}
If buttonclick = 1
{Do action}
```

Or are there any other better methods?

Comment: In computers, this is called a "double click".

Comment: Sounds like bad usability - use the standard, and show a yes-no messagebox thereby manking the user confirm his action.

Comment: Better method: do the thing on the first click, but provide a way of undoing the thing in case it was not what the user wanted.

Comment: There is no way of undoing it unfortunately as it flashes and android device back to the stock os.        I wanted to avoid yes/no message boxes as it ruins the flow of the application and I want it to be as smooth as possible. And I know it's called a double click but I swear I've seen this be used somewhere before I just can't remember where...

Comment: Instead of using a *global* variable I would suggest writing Your own custom control to handle the timer logic internally and invoke the `Click` event on the second click. This way the custom click logic would be transparent for the code outside your custom button control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure using a timer would be a good idea but I use a 3-state `ToggleButton` to achieve similar behavior.

In my solution when user clicks on my button (I call it `ConfirmCancelButton`) it turns red and waits for a second click, if the second click happens, then my "cancel command" will execute but if the button loses it's focus (e.g. user clicks somewhere else) It will be back to it's original state.

Here is a simple example:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ConfirmCancelButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="IsThreeState" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Button is not clicked (original state) -->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- Button clicked once (waiting for 2nd click)-->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- Button clicked twice (executing cancel command)-->
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
            <!-- Button lost it's focus (back to the original state)-->
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Window>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ConfirmCancelButton}" Content="Cancel" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <!-- if IsChecked=="{x:Null}" -->
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Indeterminate">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!